# Android Open SSL through JNI- org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp: not building

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface, android.mk

Hi I am trying to build openssl for android and use it through JNI by generating .SO file.

I got the reference from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/brillo-m9-dev.
and using "org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp" as JNI file. The member functions defined in NativeCrypto.cpp will be invoked from java.

org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/brillo-m9-dev/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp

Here sharing the Android.mk for reference.

Android.mk:   `

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/openssl-1.1.0/include

SRC := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(C_INCLUDES)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeFipsCrypto

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRC)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

While trying to execute the ndk-build command, It is giving the following errors. So I could not generate the .SO file.

> Build Errors:
>   `jni/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp:1051:21: error:
>   member access into incomplete type 'X509' (aka 'x509_st')
>   CRYPTO_add(&x509->references, 1, CRYPTO_LOCK_X509);
>
> jni/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp:1051:38: error: use
>   of undeclared identifier 'CRYPTO_LOCK_X509'
>   CRYPTO_add(&x509->references, 1, CRYPTO_LOCK_X509);
>
> jni/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp:1253:6: error:
>   member access into incomplete type 'BIO' (aka 'bio_st')
>       b->init = 1;
>
> jni/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp:1255:6: error:
>   member access into incomplete type 'BIO' (aka 'bio_st')
>       b->ptr = NULL;
>       `

and there are some other errors with "error: member access into incomplete type 'BIO'".

How to resolve it? What I am missing? If any android openSSL with JNI calls also can useful.

Comment: any update ? same issue

Answer (score 1):

Recent releases of AOSP use [BoringSSL](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/boringssl/+/brillo-m9-dev/) instead of OpenSSL. I am not sure if [org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/brillo-m9-dev/src/main/native/org_conscrypt_NativeCrypto.cpp) can still compile against stock OpenSSL (*it does pretend this is not impossible*), but to give it a try you must at least define all the flags following the example of AOSP [Android.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/brillo-m9-dev/Android.mk).

It will probably be easier to pull the AOSP version of BoringSSL.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have compiled the android open ssl source code(link: https://www.openssl.org/source/) and successfully generated .so file. Is there any Open SSL Java sample that calls JNI methods like NativeCrypto.cpp for the Boring SSL or FIPS SSL?

Comment: No, I am not aware of generic JNI wrappers for OpenSSL.